# Why will this Js function return undefined?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to pass in a variable that will apply to many processes within the function, but some rule im unaware of must be coming into play. It will return my passed variable, but will not return the full object including my variable as a parent...

```
var test = {number:1,color:'red'};
function Make(data){
    console.log(data)        //returns test
    console.log(test.number) //returns 1
    console.log(data,test.number) //returns test 1
    console.log(data.number) //returns undefined
};
Make("test");
```

Comment: Call `Make(test)`.

Comment: `Make("test");` should be `Make(test);`

Comment: You're confused about why the string `"test"` doesn't have a `number` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling with a string which has no property as number you should call the test object instead

```js
var test = {number:1,color:'red'};
function Make(data){
    console.log(data)        //returns test
    console.log(test.number) //returns 1
    console.log(data,test.number) //returns test 1
    console.log(data.number) //returns 1
};
Make(test);
```

Comment: Is this not a typographical mistake?

Comment: Should update comment in code

Answer (score 0):

Your function call has to be `Make(test);`.
That's because `"test"` is a string literal, means not the variable/object you're trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var test = {number:1,color:'red'};
function Make(data){
    alert(data);
    alert(test.number);
    alert(data.number);
    console.log(data)        //returns test
    console.log(test.number) //returns 1
    console.log(data,test.number) //returns test 1
    console.log(data.number) //returns undefined
};
Make(test);
```

Comment: Please add explanation. An answer with just code is not good enough. You are answering for readers and not just OP

Comment: you cannot get the property of a string.You should get the property of a variable!!

Comment: @Rajesh Hope this will help.

Comment: There already are two other answers which both point out the same issue. What is the brand new fancy theory you bring up with this answer?

Comment: I meant in the answer. An answer is something that you teach to readers. Having code is a proof of concept. Just giving code will solve the issue but it can come back. Explaining issue and solution will make sure readers do not repeat it.